# Ошибка IndexError: string index out of range программа переводит строку по типу '[7,1,15]' в числа 7, 1 и 15

Tags: python

подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка в коде, программа переводит строку по типу '[7,1,15]' в числа 7, 1 и 15

```
val_preds[1] = [7, 1, 15]
s = str(val_preds([1]))
s = s.replace('[','')
s = s.replace(']','')
s = s.replace(',','')
array_of_numbers = []
i = 0
for t in range(3): 
  st = ''
  while s[i] != ' ':
      st += s[i]
      i += 1
  i += 1
  array_of_numbers.append(int(st))
 
print(array_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

проверку на выход за границу строки не сделали:

```
while i < len(s) and s[i] != ' ':
```

кстати ваш код мог бы выглядеть так:

```
s = str([7, 1, 15])

array_of_numbers = list(map(int, s[1:-1].split(', ')))
```

или так (но тут аккуратнее надо быть):

```
import re

array_of_numbers = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))
```

или так:

```
import json

array_of_numbers = json.loads(s)
```

или так:

```
import ast

array_of_numbers = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Comment: Напишите еще про `ast.literal_eval()` и `json.loads()`, будет полезно